# Why do browsers parse "<? ?>" as "<!--? ?-->"?

Tags: html

I have a file with following the HTML code:

```
<p><? comment ?></p>
```

Curl returns a normal response:

```
$ curl file:///path/to/the/file.html
<p><? comment ?></p>
```

But when I parse that response with Firefox 69 or Chrome 77, nothing is shown to me, because the HTML code is as follows:

```
<html><head></head><body><p><!--? comment ?--></p></body></html>
```

It looks very strange for me. Why does it happen?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suspect that since it's invalid HTML the browser is doing its best to figure out what was intended, as it does with any invalid HTML.  In this case it's interpreting that as a comment.

Comment: @lurker Are you saying `<foo bar />` is invalid?

Comment: @lurker `<foo bar/>` isn’t invalid. It’s a self-closing `foo` tag with a `bar` attribute without a value.

Comment: @Kaiido Interesting. It’s still valid, though. The space doesn’t seem to matter; it’s never interpreted as self-closing, actually.

Comment: @SebastianSimon *invalid* was a poor choice of words. It's valid but not a recognized tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's part of HTML tokenizations rules.

The `<` character made your browser enter the [tag-open-state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tag-open-state).

> 12.2.5.6 Tag open state
>
> Consume the next input character:
>
> - U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK (!)
>
>   - Switch to the markup declaration open state.
> - U+002F SOLIDUS (/)
>
>   - Switch to the end tag open state.
> - ASCII alpha
>
>   - Create a new start tag token, set its tag name to the empty string. Reconsume in the tag name state.
> - U+003F QUESTION MARK (?)
>
>   - This is an [unexpected-question-mark-instead-of-tag-name](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-unexpected-question-mark-instead-of-tag-name) parse error. Create a comment token whose data is the empty string.
>   - Reconsume in the [bogus comment state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#bogus-comment-state).
> - ...

So your `?` character is handled as a known error, and then the parser switches to the [bogus comment state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#bogus-comment-state), which will put everything until the next `>` character inside the comment token.